# How to detect focus lost event on an EditText without implementing OnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I am making use of a library having an EditText and I need to detect when the focus is lost of this EditText.
The library already adds a OnFocusChangeListener on this EditText, so I can't overwrite this listener because it will break the functionality.

Is there any other way to detect when the user loses focus of an EditText?

Solution:

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalFocusChanged(View oldFocus, View newFocus) {
        //oldFocus could be null
        if (oldFocus == null || !oldFocus.equals(myEditText)) {
            return;
        }
        doYourThing();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `OnGlobalFocusChangeListener` in the `ViewTreeObserver` class. It exposes a method `onGlobalFocusChanged(View oldFocus, View newFocus)`. You just need to check if `oldFocus` is the view you are interested in.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a global boolean flag in the already implement OnFocusChangeListener on this EditText.

A global variable like  boolean isViewOnFocus = false;

and change its value in the OnFocuChangeListener. I am sure this little change will not cause any problem

Comment: Like I said, this is not possible because you can't change library code unless I make a fork of it. The solution of Danail worked.